# React-router what is $?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out if this is a react-router thing or just a React thing.  I am talking about the $ here in their example:

[react-router API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md)

```
<Link to={`/users/${user.id}`} activeClassName="current">{user.name}</Link>
```

is the `${}` a react thing?  and if so what do you call it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not a React thing.

This is a JavaScript ES6 feature:

The old way to concatenate a string :

```
var user = 'abc' + myuser;
```

ES6:

```
var user = `abc${myuser}`;
```

Answer (score 2):

`${variableName}` inside backticks is just part of es6's string interpolation system that simply just embeds the value of a variable in the given string.

For more docs and examples see [MDN - Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2):

the `${}` is the syntax for variables (or other code to be executed) inside template literals (`).

read up about template literals here: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)